# Instalar driver mongo em container apache+php

Tags: docker

Montei um `container` de acordo com o `yml` abaixo:

```
web:
 container_name: "apache"
 image: tutum/apache-php
 ports:
 - "80:80"
 volumes:
 - /home/administrador/public_html:/var/www/html
 restart: always
```

Porém a imagem utilizada não contém o driver no `mongodb`.

- Como faço para instalar o driver no `container` já montado ?
- Pelo `yml` consigo?
- Como acesso para instalar manualmente?

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nisso](https://www.gyanblog.com/gyan/47-how-connect-php-docker-container-mongo-db-docker-container/), acho que é o seu caso.

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim como sempre certeiro irmão. Valeu !

Comment: Adiciona a sua solução como resposta depois, é um caso bem interessante ;)

Comment: Estou instalando e testando. Assim que tudo tiver conferido e eu conseguir fazer funcionar posto a resposta. Realmente é bem bacana isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui instalar utilizando os seguintes comandos:

```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
   pecl install mongo
   echo "extension=mongo.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongo.ini
```

Para entrar no container e instalar utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
docker exec -it [nome_do_container] bash
```